# Is there a way to only allow UIViewControllers to adhere to a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-protocol

Is there any way to do something like this (below doesn't work):

```
@protocol ElementPicker <UIViewController>

- (id)initWithFile:(NSFileWrapper *)file andInfo:(NSString *)info;

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<ElementPickerDelegate> *delegate;
@end
```

So that objects that implement "ElementPicker" must inherit from `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Protocols can only extend other protocols. The closest you can do is define a variable, property, or parameter as being a `UIViewController` that also adheres to the `ElementPicker` protocol. Something like this:

```
- (void)someMethod:(UIViewController<ElementPicker> *)controller {
}
```

Side note - it is common to define delegates as `id`, not `NSObject`. Such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ElementPickerDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. On the side note - I've found that the compiler complains about `respondsToSelector:` not being defined when I declare the delegate as `id`.

Comment: That is fixed by making sure your delegate protocol extends the `NSObject` protocol: `@protocol ElementPickerDelegate <NSObject>`. Note that there is an `NSObject` class and an `NSObject` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the protocol can require it to be a `UIViewController`, but you can easily achieve this by setting requiring the delegate to be a `UIViewController`:

`@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController<ElementPickerDelegate> *delegate;`

Comment: I was referring to the `@protocol ElementPicker <UIViewController>` part. The delegate is just requirement of the protocol. The `<UIViewController>` doesn't work.